# How Angular 2 URL and URLs strategies works?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular 2 supports '#' in URLs as well as support URLs without '#'. 
So my question is what is the purpose of using URLs with '#' and without '#' 
 Also I see angular 2 terms `LocationStrategy` and  `HashLocationStrategy` and I googled it but found only how to use them. 
But I need to know what are they and how they actually work. 
I want some deep understanding of Angular 2 URLs mechanism and these strategies.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Comment: @Paresh Nagore thanks.yes it is helpful for me

Answer (score 1):

Basically,

The `HashLocationStrategy` will just retrieve the part after the `#` and define the page according to the link and the path.

The other way will be base around the `URL` and use of `history.pushState` to change the current page / URL without triggering a new server request. If you refresh the page while being on a custom URL, your server will redirect the request to the `index.html` file, which will handle the request, retrieve the `URL` and redirect to the right component according to the configuration.

All of these information can be easily found in the [Official Documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)